# How do i use a color scheme on vim and gvim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Both are installed on:

```
~/.vim/colors
```

And are found on the command line:

[image: Barra de comando vim]

[Link do Colorscheme - solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized)

[image: Colorscheme sky no gvim]

[Link do Colorscheme - sky](https://github.com/ninja/sky)

[image: Colorscheme sky no vim]

Comment: As can be seen, both your "colourscheme" files are actually HTML pages. How did you download them? Also see: [How do I install a plugin in Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/613/205).

Comment: You're right. They were downloaded incorrectly. The files are not supposed to have html content. I got the missing files.

Answer (score 0):

The .vim colorscheme files are not supposed to have html content. Make sure to download the raw data on the repositories.